# What is the flutter alternate for Android's WebView.settings.domStorageEnabled?

Tags: android, firebase, webview, dart, flutter

If I try to load my website in `webview` using android WebView I get error from firebase like,

**`Error: The current environment does not support the specified persistence type`**

So I added **`WebView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true`** and it started working as required.

How ever, now I'm trying the same using Flutter. I'm using the following plugin.

https://github.com/dart-flitter/flutter_webview_plugin

I get the same error now. But I couldn't find any settings like that. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/apptreesoftware/flutter_webview

Comment: You would probably need to modify the plugin and wire the setting up yourself until a better solution will be provided by the Flutter team (which I expect will happen eventually)

Answer (score 0):

The plugin you are using doesn't support that right now.

The actual plugins

- [flutter_webview_plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_webview_plugin)
- [flutter_webview](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_web_view)

still **don't support** this option.

The solution you provide is the best one if you wanna use these plugin in a legacy way.